# Loop runs too fast?

Tags: c#, loops

I have a loop (below) that loops N number of times based on user input. the loop, calls a method that creates a random string of text for an insert into a database. I want the loop to call this method before it executes the query, so every insert into the database has a different random string of characters.

What seems to be happening, is that the loop runs too quickly, and the random string is inserted about 50 times because the dynamic string variable doesn't get updated quick enough. However, if I throw in a `Thread.Sleep(50)`, the code executes perfectly.

I don't like the thread.sleep option because I don't know exactly how long it needs to sleep, and this time will add up if we start running a few hundred thousand transactions.  does anyone have a good solution to ensuring that the method executes completely before it moves on?

```
for (int i = 0; i < nLoop; i++)
{
    rnd.RndName();
    query.CommandText = "insert into XXX (col";
    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Use a `While Loop` and check if that value is in the database, if so then carry on?

Comment: Does `rnd.RndName()` create a new `Random` object each time? If so, don’t do that.

Comment: What type is `rnd`? Show us the code for `RndName`.

Comment: What do you use your random string for? If it's just to get some unique piece of information, you should consider using a GUID for that (`Guid.NewGuid()`) to avoid issues with `Random`

Comment: @ArveSystad: GUIDs have some inherent structure, even if many bits are effectively random.  See the following and note the meaning assigned to certain bit positions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What seems to be happening, is that the loop runs too quickly, and the random string is inserted about 50 times because the dynamic string variable doesn't get updated quick enough .

The instructions inside your loop will be executed one after the other.

Unless `rnd.RndName()` fires up a separate thread (in which case, show that code) it will complete before the following two statements execute.

If the name is not changing, the problem lies elsewhere.

> however, if i throw in a thread.sleep(50), the code executes perfectly.

Nothing in the code you have shown would be sensitive to a thread sleep.  If that is having some effect, the issue lies in how `rnd.RndName()` is implemented.  Perhaps you are creating a new instance of `Random` each time (as suggested in the comment by @rynah)? If so, the instance is initialized using the system time.  That would cause the behavior you observe.

The `Random` class does not really generate random numbers.  It generates a deterministic series of numbers for a given seed value.  If you seed to the current number of ticks (which I believe `Random` does), creating many `Random` instances in quick succession will cause them all to have the same seed, and therefore to produce the exact same sequence of numbers.

Comment: @rynah was correct. I mistakenly had the rnd.RndName method creating a new Random object each time. issue solved. thanks a million!